# PCL - Can't convert from Func<IThing<T>> to Func<Object> for some targets

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

I currently have a PCL library that incorporates a factory something like this (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
public abstract class ThingFactory : IThingFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<object>> _registrations = new Dictionary<string, Func<object>>();

    protected void Register<T>(string name, Func<IThing<T>> resolver) where T : IModel<T>
    {
        _registrations.Add(name, resolver);
    }

    // ... Resolve casts invocation back to IThing<T>.
}
```

The library builds and tests perfectly for .NET 4.0 above and SL 5.

Any other targets (SL 4, Windows phone etc) cause a compilation failure with the conversion message:

```
Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Func<IThing<T>>' to 'System.Func<object>'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it using this code:

```
    protected void Register<T>(string name, Func<IThing<T>> resolver) where T : IModel<T>
    {
        Func<object> wrapper =  () => resolver();
        _registrations.Add(name, wrapper);
    }
```

I guess the reason is that pre .NET 4.0 there is no variance support for func/action

Answer (score 5):

That's because `Func<T>` was declared this way in .NET 3.5

```
public delegate TResult Func<TResult>()
```

Starting from .NET4 the declaration changed to

```
public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()
```

Notice lack of `out` keyword in .NET 3.5 declaration. It makes the generic type covariant. You can read really good explanation about .NET [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) support on MSDN.